# Excel Macro to Parse Rows/Columns into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a huge sheet (Sheet1) containing multiple rows (Excel's max) and I'd like to parse this into sets of 276 rows/columns onto a separate sheet with headings.

Headings for Sheet2 would come from Column A (which is repeated 276 times so it only needs to be selected once), while Data is in C and D.

I tried to record a macro using VBA, but I don't have the knowledge to edit to loop for all of the rows.

This seems helpful, but it's not quite there.
https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/parse-functions/columns-to-sheets

Macro I recorded:

```
    Sub snp()
    '
    ' snp Macro
    ' transpose snp
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    '
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("C24566").Select
        Application.Goto Reference:="R24566C3:R24841C4"
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=252
        Range("A24841").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("FX1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
```

but this macro just does the same thing over and over again (because I don't have ANY macro knowledge to know how to make it skip to the next set of 276...).

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code makes a few assumptions:

1. You have no other sheets other than "Sheet1"
2. It's OK to call all future sheets "SheetX"
3. Only Column A is being copied
4. It doesn't matter about the last sheet having the additional blanks copied over
5. Once you've run it once, you will not need to run it again (it wont work again)
6. You have no headers on the source sheet (sheet1) or on any of the sheets it's bein copied to

Adapt this to suit your needs, but this should get you started

```
Sub Parse()

Dim SheetNum As Integer
Dim Par As Range
SheetNum = 2

Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") <> ""

Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet" & SheetNum

X = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(256, 0).Address

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:" & X).Copy

Sheets("Sheet" & SheetNum).Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:256").Delete

SheetNum = SheetNum + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

I just thought I'd expand an this answer so you **learn** something from it and can develop your VBA skills:

`Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") <> ""`
This begins the `loop` with the condition that the `loop` will run until the range in sheet 1 is `Empty`

`Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet" & SheetNum` Adds a new sheet with the sheet number

```
X = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(256, 0).Address

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:" & X).Copy

Sheets("Sheet" & SheetNum).Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:256").Delete
```

`X` is set as an address and then copied, the newly created sheet is then pasted in to with the copied cells. The original cells are then deleted.

`SheetNum = SheetNum + 1` Increment the sheet number by one before reaching the `loop` command and continuing with the loop until the criteria is set.